Optimisitic Concurrency Timestamp Error, Timestamp does not have a default value
I have an entity class as follows
  public class Order
  {
  public long Id { get; set; }

  //other properties

  [Timestamp]
  public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}

I also have the following entry in the DbContext
builder.Entity<Order>()
.Property(c => c.Timestamp).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

But when I try to add a record into the order table I get the following error

Field 'Timestamp' doesn't have a default value

How can I resolve this in ASP.Net 8, C#, Entity Framework Core and MySql

AFAIK the byte-array Timestamp works for SQL Server and possibly other RDBMS providers, but for MySQL the concurrency row versioning by default would be via a DateTime data type. This would instead be set up with the [ConcurrencyCheck] attribute, and set up in the database to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on insert and on update. I.e. in the database creation scripts:
'timestamp' datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

For code-first implementations this might require some additional research & trial & error. Something along the lines of (How to create CreatedOn and UpdatedOn using EF Core 2.1 and Pomelo) should give some ideas on how to set the default insert and update behaviour for the timestamp column.
You can also use something like an int/long (or the DateTime) for a concurrency row version and set up the DbContext to increment this automatically on save. The issue with this approach is that any external means of modifying data may not be guaranteed to alter the row version leading to data overwrites.

Thank you, for this suggestion. However, I had the concurrency working for me on MySql database with the same way it is in my question using EFCore 7 for a project I did before this one. That leads me to suspecting that the issue is with EFCore 8 because it worked as expected without issues in the other project running with EFCore 7. However, I will try your suggestions for EFCore 8 and see if it helps.

Hmm, so the MySQL provider with EF Core 7 was setting up the computed value for the byte array? Was that project setup as a code-first? You could inspect the migrations to see exactly how it was setting up the column. Something may have changed with the EF Core 8 provider. I'm not aware of any changes to the behaviour with Core 8. IF you are using code-first you might try specifying .HasComputedColumnSql() wit an appropriate default value. If this project is schema-first then the database would need to be set up with a default & update behaviour for the concurrency flag..
